# RxJs How to create stream of observables and subscribe only to the last one after delay

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have three hostlisteners after which I am subscribing to an Observable and I would like to know if it is possible and if it is how, I could create a stream of observable, with delay and subscribe only to the last one after delay.

I want to rather use hostlistener than using observable form event, and combining it, so please could you help if if something like that would be possible and how, so the this.authenticationService.refresh() would be called only once after delay of one second?

```
  @HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('window:keypress', ['$event'])
  onEvent() {
    if (this.isLoggedIn && this.timeOut) {
      this.authenticationService
        .refresh()
        .pipe(take(1),
        delay(1000),
        takeLast(1))
        .subscribe((time) => {
          console.log('tu');
          this.timeOut = time.expirationTime;
          clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
          this.setTimeout(this.timeOut);
        });
    }
```

Comment: you want the call to the authenticationService.refresh to happen after x seconds, while ignoring all clicks after the first click (so x seconds after first click -> call authenticationService.refresh()) OR if in the duration of the x seconds, a second click is made, the timer resets to back to x seconds, and in the end, only a single call to the service is made?

Comment: Exactly, but I was thinking whether it would be possible just to use rxjs to somehow every event add observable and after this delayed time subscribe to the last observable.

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand, which of the two options I listed is the desired behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Well, I would like also an advice which option from those 2 is better or preferable. I can not decide

Comment: both options are valid, depending on your use case. I don't think you need rxjs for either option, you can simply use setTimeout, do you need help with that?

Comment: Thank you very much this answers me :) I just wasn't sure which approach is the best

Answer (score 2):

I would merge those events and pipe the merged result with the `debounceTime` operator.

```
merge(
  fromEvent(window, "click").pipe(map(() => "clicked")),
  fromEvent(window, "keypress").pipe(map(() => "pressed"))
)
  .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Try the same on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-df7qwg?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

I don't think observables are needed here, what you want to accomplish can be done like this:

if you don't want to reset the timer on new clicks (just ignore more clicks):

```
debounceTime = 3000;
private currentTimeout: number;

@HostListener("window:click", ["$event"])
@HostListener("window:keypress", ["$event"])
onEvent(event) {
  if (this.currentTimeout) {
    return;
  }

  this.currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.currentTimeout = null;
    this.authenticationService.refresh();
  }, this.debounceTime);
}
```

and if you want to reset the timer every click:

```
debounceTime = 3000;
private currentTimeout: number;

@HostListener("window:click", ["$event"])
@HostListener("window:keypress", ["$event"])
onEvent(event) {
  if (this.currentTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(this.currentTimeout);
  }

  this.currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.currentTimeout = null;
    this.authenticationService.refresh();
  }, this.debounceTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't sure if using rxjs is the best here, and which approach to take, finally I decided to create a new decorator called debounceHostListeners, and it is basically doing the same as you suggested :)

Comment: glad it helped, and I really liked your idea to create a custom decorator so you can reuse the functionality!